# Including header in wrong place Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, include, laravel-blade

I'm trying to include header.blade.php first and than content, but it includs wrong way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- include navbar / header -->
  @include('site.components.header')
  <!-- content -->
  @yield('content')
  <!-- footer -->
  @include('site.components.footer')
 </body>
</html>
```

after rendering, in HTML content is included first and than header.

Comment: remove your html tags.http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Comment: do you have a `@section` content with `@stop` in your other page ?

Comment: @Isahas Why remove html tags?

Comment: thanks! I had no @stop in my content section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a section where you can include something , you need to stop it also like:

```
  @section('name of section here')
      //Your customized content for this section.
  @stop
```

While using @show immediately outputs that content that is it ends the current section and yields it. Yielding means this is the point the content of the section will be output.

```
  @section('name of section here')
      //Your customized content for this section.
  @show
```