# Laravel - HTML rendering in the wrong place

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel and i'm not quite sure yet how everything works. I'm trying to break appart code into various sections by including the begining of the page, and then create a hero section followed by some html in that page.

Everything shows but the html code that is on the page is rendering on top of everything else.

This thread looked like it could be things not being closed but as i see it everything is working as it should

[Including header in wrong place Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498281/including-header-in-wrong-place-laravel-4)

```
@include('blocks/scripts')

@extends('blocks/hero')

@section('title')
text here
@stop

@section('subtitle')
another text
@stop

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                   more text
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2 class="text-center">header</h2>
                <p class="text-center">more text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                    <h2 class="text-center">header</h2>
                    <p class="text-center">more text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@include('blocks/footer')
```

This is the file. The HTML block is being rendered right after the "scripts", followed by "footer" and then  it shows the "hero".

The order should be scripts->hero->html->footer

```
@include('blocks/scripts') just has html code
@extends('blocks/hero') has  @yield('title') and @yield('subtitle')
@include('blocks/footer') just text
```

Comment: could you add to the question how the templates `blocks/scripts.blade.php` and `blocks/hero.blade.php` look?

Comment: Hero looks like this:

`<div class="container-fuid mx-0 wlgx_hero">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
                @include('blocks/header')
            <section id="hero_text">
            <h1  class="text-center text-white py-5">@yield('title')</h1>
            <hr class="purple_line pb-3">
            <section id="subtitle">
                <p class="text-center">@yield('subtitle')</p>
            </section>
        </section>                
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

Comment: and scripts is this plus some cdn css for bootstrap and some fonts:

`<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Comment: blocks/header just has a very standard bootstrap navbar, just html no eloquent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the names of some templates because it is difficult to understand the code what you put in the comments. But I think it can help you to organize your code.

The template where you have the html, head and body tags, is not a template to be included, but to extend other templates from it, and make use of a yield. For example `@yield ('main-content')`:

**blocks/main.blade.php**:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('main-content')
    </body>
</html>
```

**blocks/hero.blade.php**
This is a template that you could extends from the main one and adding content to the `@yield('main-content')` with `@section('main-content')`:

```
@extends('blocks/main')
@section('main-content')
<div class="container-fuid mx-0 wlgx_hero"> 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-12"> 
            @include('blocks/header') 
            <section id="hero_text"> 
                <h1 class="text-center text-white py-5">
                    @yield('title')
                </h1> 
                <hr class="purple_line pb-3"> 
                <section id="subtitle"> 
                    <p class="text-center">
                        @yield('subtitle')
                    </p> 
                </section> 
            </section> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
@yield('hero-content')
@endsection('main-content')
```

The blade in your question (I don't know the name) can, in turn, extends from **hero**, and fill their yields:

```
@extends('blocks/hero')

@section('title')
text here
@stop

@section('subtitle')
another text
@stop

@section('hero-content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            more text
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-center">header</h2>
            <p class="text-center">more text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-center">header</h2>
            <p class="text-center">more text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

The last one is the view that you have to return from a route or controller, so that everything works.

Hope it's help

Comment: I've followed your instructions and it fixed my problem. Thank you very much for your time, it was indeed a confusion as to how extending sections and yields work.

Answer (score 2):

In blade files, every direct HTML outside of `@section('something')` will be rendered at the top of the file.

You need to put `@yield('something')` in the extended file then wrap your HTML code with `@section('something')` and `@endsection('something')` like what you do with **title** and **subtitle**.